# Why doesn't Perl 6's colon pair and name interpolation work together?

Tags: raku

I was playing around with [Interpolating into names](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#Interpolating_into_names). I was mostly interested in this colon syntax feature to turn a variable into a pair where the identifier is the key.

```
my %Hamadryas = map { slip $_, 0 }, <
    februa
    honorina
    velutina
    >;

{
my $pair = :%Hamadryas;
say $pair;   # Hamadryas => { ... }
}

put '-' x 50;
```

But, just for giggles, I wanted to try it with variable name interpolation too. I know this is stupid because if I know the name I don't need the colon syntax to get it. But, I also thought that it should work by accident:

```
{
my $name = 'Hamadryas';
# Since I already have the name, I could just:
# my $pair = $name => %::($name)

# But, couldn't I just line up the syntax?
my $pair = :%::($name);  # does not work
say $pair;
}
```

Why doesn't that `:%::($name)` syntax work? That's more a question of when the parser decides that it's not parsing something it wants to understand. I figured it would see the `:` and start processing a colon pair, then see the `%` and know it had a hash, even though there's the `::` after the `%`.

Is there a way to make it work with tricks and grammar mutations?

Comment: *Is there a way to make it work?* not without hacking the [Perl6 grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/f4017c3/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L1923..L1929), which can in principle be done in userspace via slangs

Comment: Yeah, I'm almost never interested in hacking the grammar. I was more wondering how the parser fails. I don't really want it to work. But if the answer is no (along with a suitable reason), that's an answer I can accept.

Comment: Hacking of the Perl 6 grammar would be about: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L1879 and https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L2392 .  Pull Requests are welcome!

Comment: This is now referenced in [this Rakudo issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1532)